# How to take first one or two digits from float number?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe. In a series, I have time in hour and minute represented as `float`, as below. I want only the hours:

**Example of time column values from (1 to 12) :**

```
1000.0 -> 10
901.0 ->  9
```

**Example of time column values from (13 to 24) :**

```
1850.0 -> 18
2301.0 -> 23
```

I have tried this code but it takes very long time until I close the editor so I didn't see the result

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if(row['time']<=959.0):
        row['hour']= int(str(row['dep_time'])[:1])
    elif row['dep_time']>959.0: 
         row['dep_hour']=int(str(row['dep_time'])[:2])
```

Comment: `1000.0 // 100`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code fails for lack of `df`, and you have no known problem to give us.  You need both for a viable Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Pandas, don't iterate rows when vectorised methods are available. In this case, you can use floor division followed by [`pd.Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['hour'] = (df['dep_time'] // 100).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this with floor division and `int` cast?

```
>>> int(1000.0 // 100)
10
>>> int(901.0 // 100)
9
>>> int(1850.0 // 100)
18
>>> int(2301.0 // 100)
23
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest option here is to use the "modulo" (%) function:

```
time=1234.0
minutes=time%100 #gets the last 2 digits
hours=(time-minutes)/100
print(minutes)
print(hours)
```

A better option would be to define the time using the datetime library and build on this (here is a link to the documentation :https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)